# Detecção de user agent para redirecionamenrto

Tags: php

Gostaria de identificar o IE e redirecioná-los a outra página. Peguei o exemplo no manual PHP mas dá um erro.

```
<?php 
 if (strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],"MSIE"))
{
 echo"IE";
 } else {echo"Outro";}
?>
```

O erro apresentado

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'  on line 3

Comment: O erro de sintaxe não está nessas linhas.

Comment: É o primeiro { que esta na linha três apenas modifiquei aqui para ficar junto mas o código é só esse não tem mais nada é apenas uma pagina de teste

Comment: não tem nada errado...

Comment: O interpretador pode se perder em erros de sintaxe, ele pode indicar uma linha porque ali foi possível identificar que existe um erro mas na verdade a origem real do erro pode estar em outra linha. Vou dar uma dica: se tentar caprichar na organização do seu código fica bem mais fácil entendê-lo e achar possíveis erros. Só porque pode escrever tudo amontoado não significa que deva. Serve inclusive para organizar melhor o pensamento sobre o algoritmo. O cérebro humano trabalha melhor assim.

Comment: Mas não existe outras linhas apenas essas, como avia dito apenas modifiquei para ficar tudo junto aqui mas a linha 3 se encontra o primeiro { já pesquisei em vários sites todos tem exemplos parecidos mas não funciona não sei se pode ser problema com wamp?

Comment: Duvido que seja o WAMP. Este código está correto e nem tem 3 linhas, por isto é impossível só ter estas linhas. Olha funcionando: http://ideone.com/FuWm2s Tem um outro problema nele, mas é por outro motivo.

Comment: Poste seu código **exatamente** como está na sua máquina (não sei se é do jeito que o @KaduAmaral colocou).

Comment: E revise o erro também se agora está apresentando outra mensagem. Agora ficou mais difícil ainda ter erro na linha 3. De qualquer forma, amontoado, o erro vai ser na linha 1, poderia ter vários, todos estariam na linha 1 do jeito que está no comentário. Separar o código em várias linhas não é frescura, é importante para facilitar a manutenção.

Comment: Obrigado é exatamente assim que esta!!! realmente não sei pq deve dar esse erro continuo pesquisando em varios foruns e todos são exemplos parecidos e como todos aqui dizem que não tem erro fica mais dificil!!!

Comment: É pouco provável que esteja **exatamente** assim. Em programas qualquer detalhe mínimo que seja pode fazer diferença. Sem vermos cada caractere não temos o que fazer. Você vai ter que chamar algum programador experiente que você conheça aí para te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa maneira de começar a resolver seu problema é identificando onde o PHP está registrando a variável do User-Agent. O User-Agent é um cabeçalho HTTP e é mandado em toda requisição.

Comece fazendo uma página em PHP com o código:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Essa página vem com um monte de informações sobre o PHP: qual a versão, se está instalado em servidor Apache ou qualquer outro e... também tem os cabeçalhos e por sua vez o User-Agent passado pelo navegador! Procure pelo seu navegador fazendo uma busca com CTRL+F na página.

Aqui no meu exemplo, temos a linha:

```
PHP Variables
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
```

Repare que no meu servidor, o seu código funciona! Mas pode ser que seu servidor seja outro, e então essa variável pode ser outra.

Sobre algo relacionado, também é possível fazer um código[1] e ver todas os cabeçalhos HTTP, incluindo o User-Agent:

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
  echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
?>
```

Mas isso só funciona em servidores Apache-like.

[1] Fonte: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php